# Linux Man command help

Tags: linux, manpages, pager, man

Are there any tricks/sites/methods to use the linux man command in a more convenient way ? I love commands in terminal but for some strange reason I preferred to type man in firefox then in the terminal. The output is so long and I have to scroll forever to find what I need. Also the lack of example is a headache.

Comment: An alternative to the more proper responses might be to create a custom search word in Firefox for "man" and point it to [Linux Man Pages](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/). Then you can type man <thing> in Firefox and have it work. Still, it's worth getting used to man itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `man` pager is `less`, you can search for regexes by using `/`. For example, to search for examples in `man find`, type `/^examples`. You can use page-up and page-down and other usual navigation keys to move around.

Comment: Also, to repeat the search use `n`; `N` to do the same in the reverse direction.

Comment: Yep. More or less any pager you'll find these days has a search command, so learn to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need:

`man man`

Comment: Actually `man less` is more likely to be relevant. Or typing `h` in less.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `xman` which is a GUI man page viewer on almost all systems.  Others must exist as well.

Some Linux distros still keep info pages, which are a hypertext sort of replacement for man pages.  It never got much traction, so not all commands have info pages.  I never liked them personally but you may like them. Look at the `info`, `pinfo` or even `tkinfo` commands.

Remember that man uses nroff underneath (groff on Linux) and it can target a small subset of output types.  I find postscript output useful, either with ghostview/kghostview on screen, or just dumping to a printer.  I think the `-t` flag in most distros will dump to postscript.  Or maybe the sequence `-p -Tps`.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing man2html.  This will allow you to browse the man pages in Firefox or whatever browser you want to use.